# PCRE - perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I am trying to make an regex in PCRE for string detection. The kind of strings I want to detect are abcdef001, zxyabc003. A word with first 6 characters are a-zA-Z and last two or three are digits 0-9; and this string could be anywhere in the whole text.

E.g - "User activity from server1, user id `abcdef009`, time 10.20am".

How do I go about this?

Comment: If you're getting started with regex, I'd recommend http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
/[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2,3}/
```

If you want to limit it to whole words, try:

```
/\b[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2,3}\b/
```

- `\b` - word boundry
- `[a-zA-Z]{6}` - six letters
- `[0-9]{2,3}` - either 2 or 3 numbers
- `\b` - word boundry

Comment: what does the `/` here mean?

Comment: In Perl, regular expressions are typically surrounded by slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex pattern

```
/[a-z]{6}\d{2,3}/i
```